# get path after index page in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

in php, we can get the path after the index page, for example if the URL is `http://server.com/index.php/resource/name`, we can get the path 'resource' and 'name'. in jsp, it doesn't work. URL `http://server.com/index.jsp/resource/name` outputs '404 not found'. i'm thinking like ignoring the path after index page or welcome page maybe. any idea how to get these paths 'resource' and 'name' in jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't, JSP should contain your view, but no logic.  It's simple to do what you want with a servlet, by using the servlet mapping.  For example, assuming you have a  servlet named index and this section in your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This will match `http://server.com/index/resource/name`.  There are several methods in the Request object your servlet will receive that allow you to see the different path elements, like [getQueryString](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) or [getContextPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) or [getPathInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29).

Comment: ah, so the tag url-pattern can be used like that. thank you so much, it works!